What are the syntactic correct way of using GPU delegates for assisting tensorflow-lite model in python?
I'm currently working on yocto linux image on NXP and I want you use tflite model. I want to use GPU delegate instead of CPU delegate inorder to run the model. What will be the correct way of doing this ?
I have explored a couple of ways in which one of them is suggesting that you need to have lib_tensorflow_gpu_delegate.so file present in the system. I have tried to install it by cloning the tensorflow official repo and do the certain steps but unable to do so. I'm also not sure that whether this is accurate or not.
